# CSS calc() - Multiplication and Division with unit-ed values

Tags: css, css-calc

Is it possible to use calc() to multiply or divide with unit-based values (like 100%, 5px, etc).

For example I was hoping to do something like this:

```
width: calc(100% * (.7 - 120px / 100%));
```

Hoping it resolved to something like (assuming 100% = 500px):

```
width: calc(500px * (.7 - 120px / 500px));
width: calc(500px * (.7 - .24));
width: calc(500px * .46);
width: calc(230px);
```

However after some experimenting it looks like I can't have a unit-based value as the denominator for division.

I also don't seem to be able to multiple two values together like `5px * 10px` or `5px * 100%`.

I know it doesn't make sense in 100% of the cases to allow this, but in my use-case, I'd like to know what percentage 120px is of the overall width, which I then feed in to the rest of my calculation.

Either that, or if someone could figure out a different way to write it, that would work as well. I've racked my brain and couldn't come up with anything.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

In CSS calc() division - the right side must be a `<number>` therefore unit based values cannot be used in division like this.

Also note that in multiplication at least one of the arguments must be a number.

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) has great documentation on this.

If you'd like a better way to do calculations you can use a preprocessor (I like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/guide)). That link will take you to their guides (on that page there's a section about operators).

Comment: Wow... I read that page like 5 times looking for that rule. I'm not sure how I missed it sitting right there next to the description of the operators. Thanks. That's what I was afraid of. I am actually using LESS, though the formula I gave you above I need to calculate with calc() since I need to know the width, which is variable. Back to the drawing board to find an all together different approach. Thanks for the definitive answer, at least now I know this way is a dead end.

Comment: Preprocessors can't handle as much as calc() can, since such calculations need to be done at render time, which makes something like Sass useless.

Comment: That spec says both the numerator and the denominator can be numbers, shouldn't something like this then work: `calc(100 / 2)`?

Comment: Yes, that works. The numerator can also be a unit such as px though.

Comment: If CSS's `calc()` function is restrained to such an *astronomical* degree, why is there no way to cast a variable as a number in CSS? As far as I know, there's no way to put CSS variables into SASS given that it's a preprocessor.

Answer (score 12):

For someone who is making a mistake like me, don't forget that you can't use **Sass variables** in CSS's `calc` function directly. For that, you have to use Sass's calculation method.

```
$test: 10px;

.testing{
    width: $test * 2;
}
```

Or if a `calc` implementation is necessary:

```
$test: 10px;

.testing{
  width: calc(50% + #{$test * 2}); // results in calc(50% - 20px)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the near future, it will be possible as defined in [the Specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values/#calc-type-checking)

> NOTE: In previous versions of this specification, multiplication and division were limited in what arguments they could take, to avoid producing more complex intermediate results (such as 1px * 1em, which is ²) and to make division-by-zero detectable at parse time. **This version now relaxes those restrictions**.

Then you can read some complex rules that allow multiplying and dividing types