# Calc() pixel height dynamically based on dynamic width and ratio with CSS

Tags: css

Been trying what seems to be an uphill battle.

I have an image, 768px x 411px. It must be fixed because it is part of a javascript scratch game. It can be resized though, but it must have fixed values.

My idea is the set the width to 100vw, then calculate the aspect ratio of the image and then base don that ratio, calculate the height from the current image width value.

I've been reading up a lot but no luck thusfar. Is this not possible with CSS alone? Here's part of my code:

```
        :root{
            --defaultWidth: 768px;
            --defaultHeight: 411px;
            --widthMain: calc(100% - 5px);                 
            --perspective: calc( var(--defaultHeight) / var(--defaultWidth) );
        }
        .scratchpad {
            width: var(--widthMain);
            height: calc( var(--widthMain) * var(--perspective) );
        /* also tried variations of this
            height: calc( calc(var(--widthMain) * var(--perspective)) ); */
        }
        .scratch-container {
            -webkit-touch-callout: none;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -khtml-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            width:100%;
        }
```

Thanks.

EDIT:
Can't say I'm proud but I hacked myself into a temp solution by mixing it up with PHP

```
        <?php
    // Calling getimagesize() function 
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize("cover.png");
    $ratio   =  $height/$width;
    ?>

    <style type="text/css">
        :root{
            --defaultWidth: <?=$width?>px;
            --defaultHeight: <?=$height?>px;
            --widthMain: calc(100vw - 15px);                 
            --perspective: calc( var(--defaultHeight) / var(--defaultWidth) );
        }
        html {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        *, *:before, *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }
        .scratchpad {
            width: var(--widthMain);
            height: calc((100vw - 15px) * <?= $ratio; ?> );
            border: solid 2px #fff;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
```

Comment: Is the image displayed with a HTML <img> element? In that case, just don't set the `height` at all; keep it at its default of `auto`.

Comment: That doesn't work. It will render to a height of 0. On the original page it also says there must be a set width and height (source: https://jennamolby.com/interactive-scratch-and-win-landing-page-tutorial/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by exploiting the fact that `padding-top` and `padding-top` reference the parent width when using relative units (e.g. 50% is half the width of the parent):

```css
.container-a {
  width: 180px;
}

.container-b {
  width: 100px;
}

.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;

  /* Image aspect ratio as a percentage */
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
 
img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-a">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x100" />
  </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="container-b">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="//placehold.it/200x100" />
  </div>
</div>
```

See how the image resizes, but it and the `.image-wrapper` element maintain the correct aspect ratio?

Comment: Thank you Corey, I upvoted for your effort and obviously this works in some cases but it does not answer my question as to how to use calc the right way.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29505279/css-calc-multiplication-and-division-with-unit-ed-values